# How to get Azure Virtual Machine Details via .NET API?

Tags: azure, msdn, azure-vm-role

How do you get vm details through Azure .NET API such as fqdn, ipAddress, machine state, etc? I can't find this functionality in the MSDN documentation or elsewhere.

Comment: Take a look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx

Comment: be aware that the virtual machine is wrapped in a hosted service. So look for the API for the hosted service might help.